# JSON.NET: Unable to translate Unicode character

Tags: c#, json, text, unicode, json.net

I implemented a search tree that contain some texts. Now, I'm want to allow the client to save this tree to disk - serilize. So, I'm using JSON.Net to serilize this object to disk. Since I'm handlig huge text files (50MB+), I'm serilize this object directly to DISK (instead of get string that contain this JSON).

This is my current code:

```
public void Save(string path)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(jw, this);
    }
}
```

This is the exception I'm got:

```
exception: 
    System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uD859 at index 485 to specified code page.
    Result StackTrace:  
    at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
       at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
       at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(Char* chars, Int32 charCount, Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
       at System.Text.EncoderNLS.GetBytes(Char* chars, Int32 charCount, Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Boolean flush)
       at System.Text.EncoderNLS.GetBytes(Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Int32 charCount, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Boolean flush)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
    ...
```

The file that not pass the test is file that contains chanise characters (not sure that this is the problem).

How I'm can fix this?

Comment: Well U+D859 isn't a valid Unicode character on its own - it's part of a surrogate pair. My guess is that some part of your data is invalid... you should work out where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a JSON problem, it's a StreamWriter problem, it encounters a character that it cannot encode. Try to open it like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Unicode))
```